# Accessing the img directory from scripts and css files

Tags: javascript, css, html5boilerplate

I am using the html5 boilerplate layout which has a css, img, and js directory at the same level. I am having all kinds of issues accessing images from my .css files and .js files. I have been warned that using `../` may cause problems, but without some kind of url generator (like I have with my template files), how can I best access images from my .js and .css files?

Comment: If you are using a template engine like smarty , you can set an APP_BASE_URL and use it in your template engine like {$APP_BASE_URL}js/ and {$APP_BASE_URL}css/ and {$APP_BASE_URL}images/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One robust way to access static resources in CSS is to always give the full path:

```
body {
    background-image: url("/path/to/image.png");
}
```

Notice the preceding `/` character. It tells the browser to look for the file at the root of the server. For example, if you currently are on `http://example.com/pictures/album/5` then the above CSS will find the background at `http://example.com/path/to/image.png`.

Using the full path also encourages you to keep your resources well organized.

This is not to say that using relative paths is a bad thing, though. If you are working on a CSS project and put it in a sub-folder, say `/static/myproject/project.css`, then you can refer to images in that folder using relative paths.

If we say that your project is at `/static/myproject`, and the folder structure looks like this:

```
/static/myproject/project.css
/static/myproject/back-button.gif
/static/myproject/forward-button.gif
```

Then, in your CSS file, you can call the images relative to the CSS file:

```
.back {
    background-image: url("back-button.gif");
}
.forward {
    background-image: url("forward-button.gif");
}
```

The problem with doing it like this is that resources tend to be stored all over the place. That makes it more difficult to reuse resources.

Comment: I wonder how well this fares when using a CDN, like Amazon's CloudFront? Would pre-pending the `/` cause it to look from the source directory of the CDN? If not, would using the `../` still work when traversing the CDN directory?

Comment: @FloatingRock No, if you are using a CDN then you need to give the full URI (e.g. `http://your-cdn.com/path/to/image.gif`). CDNs are basically just geographically distributed hard disks where you put your files, and they have no knowledge of what your HTML `href`s/`src`s point at.